# Args is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I used a role color changer peice of code, and it was pretty cool, until I uploaded it to glitch.com, now all I get is the "args is not defined" error again, here is a small chunk of the code I was using

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 75;

var red = ['#ff0000']

client.on('message', message => {   
    if (message.content.startsWith('grimm!change red')) {
        message.channel.send('color for changed to Red')
        const colorRole = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find(R => R.name === args.join(" "));
        colorRole.edit({
            color: red[0]
        
    })
}})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

could anyone tell me how I could possibly fix this? I have been researching everywhere but I have no clue on how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Your code uses `args` but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Where is `args` supposed to come from?

Comment: I guess the error explains it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
client.on('message', message => {
  ...
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  ...
});
```

[Command with user input](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments)